# How to get Google Cloud Messaging response into a Service worker's event for notifications in Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

The message is being received and notification does pop up when I use an example text for notification.

I've set up an account with Google for push notifications on Chrome, but the response appears to be empty.

**THE SERVICE WORKER**

I have this on the service worker, but its empty.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  //console.log('Received a push message', event);
  console.log(event.data);
});
```

Then there's one other thing I've tried with Fetch, using the localhost url.

```
var url = 'http://localhost/notification/index.php?type=fg';
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(fetch(url).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
            return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          //'data' does't have the json from the url
      })
    )
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` print in your console? Can you add a `.catch` at the end of the promise chain and log to see if there's any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome doesn't support push payloads yet, so the first snippet will only work in Firefox (https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload.html).

Your second approach, instead, should work in any browser (https://serviceworke.rs/push-get-payload.html).

Comment: I'm going to try the code on the link, but it would be proper if the relevant code could be put inline on this answer for easy reference.